# Can I install Ubuntu desktop programs on my Nexus 4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

I'm asking this question because I want to work on my phone, not on my PC in the office.

I read that Ubuntu can be installed on the Nexus 4, the phone I have, and can be used as a complete PC. I also searched the web for connecting the device to a monitor and I found SlimPort. Bluetooth keyboard and mouse could do the trick.

The question is:

- How to switch to desktop mode?
- Can I install Ubuntu desktop applications?

Mostly I'm interested on installing Eclipse. A video demonstrating this would be nice.

Comment: As there are no videos on youtube this feature is probably not yet available. Ubuntu mobile is just a beta/developer version, so I would not recommend using it to work with until it leaves beta status, even if the hdmi connection would work. I think the phone will detect whether it has a screen plugged in and a keyboard connected and then switches the desktop mode by itself. But this is only a guess (and a recommendation not to use a beta to work with), so maybe someone has a more positive answer.

Comment: @chocobai, you could add this as an answer. As of now you are right about Ubuntu-for-android being in a development/beta state.

Answer (score 1):

As there are no videos on youtube this feature is probably not yet available. Ubuntu mobile is just a beta/developer version, so I would not recommend using it to work with until it leaves beta status, even if the hdmi connection would work. I think the phone will detect whether it has a screen plugged in and a keyboard connected and then switches the desktop mode by itself. But this is only a guess (and a recommendation not to use a beta to work with), so maybe someone has a more positive answer.

**Update** There is a first video from canonical showing this feature. It still seems to be relatively slow since it's in beta state. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/07/ubuntu-edge-convergence-shown-off

As far as I know this feature is not yet enabled in the public release, but unfortunately I can't test it. If you consider buying a new phone, take a look at the Ubuntu Edge: http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge

Please notice the device will be delivered in spring next year.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get right now is installing Ubuntu Touch on your Nexus 4, using apt-get to install certain packages (Firefox, etc) and using X11 forwarding from another computer.  It's not what "Ubuntu for Android" promises, but technically you'd be running desktop apps off your phone.

I've been playing with this for fun with mine.  It's really just for goofy/nerdy fun.

Basic steps to do this:

1. Install Ubuntu Touch https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install
2. on the phone (now running Ubuntu Touch) use Terminal to do "sudo apt-get install openssh-server xauth xterm" (The password is
   'phablet')
3. make sure phone and laptop/desktop are on the same Wifi network and get your phone's ip address using the command "ifconfig"
4. from another computer with X11 installed (I've used my Mac laptop and other Linux desktops) login to the phone with: ssh -X
   phablet@192.168.1.103 (or whatever the IP is).
5. From here you
   can run the command "xterm" or any other command ("firefox") to run
   apps after you have installed them using apt-get.